# Is it possible to lock memory used by common controls in my application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, virtual-memory, common-controls

I'm writing an application that encrypts its data. It can then display it unencrypted using the app's UI after a user enters password. My goal is to minimize exposure of plaintext data while in RAM. For that I want to prevent swapping it to disk as much as possible.

I know that I can adjust my process's working set (by calling [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx) API) and then lock those sensitive pages in RAM (by calling [VirtualLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx).) That, in theory, should minimize the chances of it being written to disk.

The question I have is, can I do the same with the memory that is used by the common controls in my dialog window, namely in [Edit boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx), [combo boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775792(v=vs.85).aspx), and most importantly [RichEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605(v=vs.85).aspx) control?

PS. I'm assuming that they all use data from the [heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711(v=vs.85).aspx) for my process. Correct?

**EDIT:** *Seeing all the comments below I need to clarify. By saying "lock", I don't mean, "lock it with a padlock and key so that no one can see it." I meant, lock it as with the `VirtualLock` API.*

Comment: The attackers aren't going to hunt for this on the disk. They can just read it out of memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm not asking for that.

Comment: Have you hired a white hat to attack your app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The app that hasn't been written yet. Did you have your coffee today?

Comment: Great. Now is the perfect time to get some expert help in so that you have confidence that you design it right.

Comment: now yes - all common controls allocate memory from heap. even more concrete from this - `GetProcessHeap` heap. heap is only several blocks of memory allocated by `VirtualAlloc`. all it can be enumerated via `HeapWalk` and lock. another question - are this really have sense. but this formally possible

Comment: @RbMm: Good info. Thank you. Can I ask, where are you taking this information from? And again -- **I AM NOT** trying to protect against malicious process "piping into" my running app. In despite of the condescending remarks above, I understand that that is impossible to do (on a Windows platform.)

Comment: that common controls allocate memory from main process heap - primary from my experience - this is not documented and not guarantee - but from where, if not from heap ? about concrete edit control - look [`EM_GETHANDLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761576(v=vs.85).aspx) - this prove that edit control allocate own buffer from main process heap - `LocalLock` worked only with memory allocated by `LocalAlloc` which always allocated only from main process heap. that heap memory allocated by `VirtualAlloc` this already 100%.

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, I see your point. Thanks. Obviously all user-mode memory allocations boil down to using `VirtualAlloc` (or `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` or whatever it's called.) So, yeah, I guess if I periodically `HeapLock` from a worker thread, then do `HeapWalk` and quickly collect all virtual memory pages used, then `HeapUnlock` and then call `VirtualLock` on the result. That should hypothetically do the job, hah?

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/nYPqc91t) code enumerate all heap blocks allocated by `VirtualAlloc` on current time

Comment: @RbMm: Hey, sorry for the delay. I just got to reviewing your code, but I'm struggling to understand what exactly you're doing there. For instance, why are you calling `VirtualQuery` twice on a `PROCESS_HEAP_REGION` block, first with `Entry.lpData` and then with `mbi.AllocationBase`?

Comment: @c00000fd -  yes, this is my mistake here. in general *AllocationBase != BaseAddress* in case this [code](https://pastebin.com/m43bjNDA) need single *VirtualQuery* only

Comment: @RbMm: I implemented your suggestions. Although ran into a new issue. Can you [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44316994/843732)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EM_SETHANDLE` to set a handle for an edit control's initial allocation, then respond to `EN_ERRSPACE` when (if) it runs out of space and needs more.

From there, it's up to you to also use `VirtualLock` on that block of memory to keep it in RAM as much as possible. If you're going to do this a lot, you probably want to consider superclassing the control(s) to keep from duplicating the code everywhere.

For better or worse, I don't believe there's an equivalent for rich text controls though.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I didn't know that such style existed. I'm [reading though](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172(v=vs.85).aspx), "Applies to 16-bit applications only." Also what about RichEdit? Can you clarify.

Comment: The reference to DS_LOCALEDIT was probably misplaced--a reflection of my advanced age, I'm afraid.

Comment: `DS_LOCALEDIT` really was need very many years ago for 16-bit app. now always edit allocated memory from main process heap

Comment: `EN_ERRSPACE` here not useful. it called when *edit control cannot allocate enough memory* - so process out of memory. when text length in edit control is changed and need new buffer - edit simply call `LocalReAlloc` without any notify parent window

Comment: @RbMm: Yes and no. Yes, it can and will reallocate--but if you've given it a handle to a heap that you created with `HeapCreate`, then you set the maximum size for the heap, and when/if it runs out of space, it's up to you to create a large heap and give it a handle into the new heap (at least that seems like how it *should* work--I haven't tested to be sure, at least not recently).

Comment: *but if you've given it a handle to a heap that you created with HeapCreate* - how ? `EM_SETHANDLE` set address of memory block but not of heap. edit control always worked with `LocalAlloc`, `LocalFree`, `LocalRealloc` functions (this i view under debugger) - it worked only with main process heap. if you pass him block from another heap - `LocalReallock` raise exception (checked)

Comment: @RbMm: You know, if you write up your proposed `HeapWalk` implementation, that may be a better solution. I'm trying to throw in a test code myself now. To see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a native windows API to help minimize the exposure of crucial items like passwords to memory scraping.

See [CryptProtectMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380262(v=vs.85).aspx) as a starting point.

Comment: Well, Chris, how would I made an edit box use it, c'mon. I can use it myself to store PBKDF hash. That's true.

Comment: I don't think you can. The API makes it clear that its intended use is to minimize the exposure of sensitive data, not lock it totally. It is not an end-to-end solution.

Comment: That API is to "scramble" my own data. For instance, like I said, I use it to store `PBKDF2` hash while in memory. That works only for the data that you control. Like that hash.

Comment: You are showing the data on the screen. Any attacker that can read memory or your disk can also see your screen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm talking about not exposing a user password. And not the data on the screen.

Comment: Unless you are writing a tool like last pass you don't store passwords

Comment: and if you are getting into storing passwords territory, instead of rolling your own, you should be using the Credentials Management API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374791(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Chris, I appreciate your tidbits of wisdom, but what does this all have to do with the question that I'm asking?

Comment: It was my recollection that, when I read the CryptProtectMemory docs many years ago, that a section dealt with best practices, around, e.g. how to minimise the chance that sensitive data would be paged out.