# CString use coupled with HeapWalk and HeapLock/HeapUnlock deadlocks in the kernel

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, heap-memory

My goal is to lock virtual memory allocated for my process heaps (to prevent a possibility of it being swapped out to disk.)

I use the following code:

```
//pseudo-code, error checks are omitted for brevity

struct MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK{
    const BYTE* pBaseAddr;          //Base address of the page
    size_t szcbBlockSz;         //Size of the block in bytes

    MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK()
        : pBaseAddr(NULL)
        , szcbBlockSz(0)
    {
    }
};


void WorkerThread(LPVOID pVoid)
{
    //Called repeatedly from a worker thread

    HANDLE hHeaps[256] = {0};   //Assume large array for the sake of this example
    UINT nNumberHeaps = ::GetProcessHeaps(256, hHeaps);
    if(nNumberHeaps > 256)
        nNumberHeaps = 256;

    std::vector<MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK> arrPages;

    for(UINT i = 0; i < nNumberHeaps; i++)
    {
        lockUnlockHeapAndWalkIt(hHeaps[i], arrPages);
    }

    //Now lock collected virtual memory
    for(size_t p = 0; p < arrPages.size(); p++)
    {
        ::VirtualLock((void*)arrPages[p].pBaseAddr, arrPages[p].szcbBlockSz);
    }

}

void lockUnlockHeapAndWalkIt(HANDLE hHeap, std::vector<MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK>& arrPages)
{
    if(::HeapLock(hHeap))
    {
        __try
        {
            walkHeapAndCollectVMPages(hHeap, arrPages);
        }
        __finally
        {
            ::HeapUnlock(hHeap);
        }
    }
}

void walkHeapAndCollectVMPages(HANDLE hHeap, std::vector<MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK>& arrPages)
{
    PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY phe = {0};

    MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK mptl;

    SYSTEM_INFO si = {0};
    ::GetSystemInfo(&si);

    for(;;)
    {
        //Get next heap block
        if(!::HeapWalk(hHeap, &phe))
        {
            if(::GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            {
                //Some other error
                ASSERT(NULL);
            }

            break;
        }

        //We need to skip heap regions & uncommitted areas
        //We're interested only in allocated blocks
        if((phe.wFlags & (PROCESS_HEAP_REGION | 
            PROCESS_HEAP_UNCOMMITTED_RANGE | PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY)) == PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY)
        {
            if(phe.cbData &&
                phe.lpData)
            {
                //Get address aligned at the page size boundary
                size_t nRmndr = (size_t)phe.lpData % si.dwPageSize;
                BYTE* pBegin = (BYTE*)((size_t)phe.lpData - nRmndr);

                //Get segment size, also page aligned (round it up though)
                BYTE* pLast = (BYTE*)phe.lpData + phe.cbData;
                nRmndr = (size_t)pLast % si.dwPageSize;
                if(nRmndr)
                    pLast += si.dwPageSize - nRmndr;

                size_t szcbSz = pLast - pBegin;

                //Do we have such a block already, or an adjacent one?
                std::vector<MEM_PAGE_TO_LOCK>::iterator itr = arrPages.begin();
                for(; itr != arrPages.end(); ++itr)
                {
                    const BYTE* pLPtr = itr->pBaseAddr + itr->szcbBlockSz;

                    //See if they intersect or are adjacent
                    if(pLPtr >= pBegin &&
                        itr->pBaseAddr <= pLast)
                    {
                        //Intersected with another memory block

                        //Get the larger of the two
                        if(pBegin < itr->pBaseAddr)
                            itr->pBaseAddr = pBegin;

                        itr->szcbBlockSz = pLPtr > pLast ? pLPtr - itr->pBaseAddr : pLast - itr->pBaseAddr;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(itr == arrPages.end())
                {
                    //Add new page
                    mptl.pBaseAddr = pBegin;
                    mptl.szcbBlockSz = szcbSz;

                    arrPages.push_back(mptl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method works, except that rarely the following happens. The app hangs up, UI and everything, and even if I try to run it with the Visual Studio debugger and then try to `Break all`, it shows an error message that no user-mode threads are running:

> The process appears to be deadlocked (or is not running any user-mode
>   code).  All threads have been stopped.

[image]

I tried it several times. The second time when the app hung up, I used the Task Manager to `create dump file`, after which I loaded the `.dmp` file into Visual Studio & analyzed it. The debugger showed that the deadlock happened somewhere in the kernel:

[image]

and if you review the call stack:

[image]

It points to the location of the code as such:

```
CString str;

str.Format(L"Some formatting value=%d, %s", value, etc);
```

Experimenting further with it, if I remove `HeapLock` and `HeapUnlock` calls from the code above, it doesn't seem to hang anymore. But then `HeapWalk` may sometimes issue an unhandled exception, access violation.

So any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: You may want to hook Visual Studio up to the Microsoft Symbol Server (or download the symbol files locally) so the stack trace won't be obtuse about which system call you're in.

Comment: @andlabs: it's freeing the memory allocated by CString, i.e. `_free_dbg_nolock()`

Comment: *All* deadlocks take place in the kernel, unless you're using spinlocks I guess.  Nothing unusual here.  I think your problem is that you're using C++ standard library classes, in particular std::vector, while the heap is locked.  You probably need to avoid all C and C++ library functionality, anything that might try to claim a lock that another thread could be holding.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks. But I disagree. C and C++ library functions use heap allocations internally for its memory management. `HeapAlloc` to be precise. Well, that API in turn uses a critical section that can be locked by `HeapLock`. So as you know locking a critical section and trying to enter it from the same thread has no effect, thus one can easily call memory allocations from the same thread after the heap is locked. The issue here must be something else. My guess is that `CString::Format` doesn't use serialized heap, or `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE`, but I can't seem to find any references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the C runtime's memory management, and more specifically the CRT's debug heap, while holding the operating system's heap lock.

The call stack you've posted includes `_free_dbg`, which always claims the CRT debug heap lock before taking any other action, so we know the thread holds the CRT debug heap lock.  We can also see that the CRT was inside an operating system call made by `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` when the deadlock occurred; the only such call is to [`HeapValidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366708(v=vs.85).aspx) and `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` is not specified.

So the thread whose call stack has been posted is holding the CRT debug heap lock and attempting to claim the operating system's heap lock.

The worker thread, on the other hand, holds the operating system's heap lock and makes calls that attempt to claim the CRT debug heap lock.

QED.  Classic deadlock situation.

In a debug build, you will need to refrain from using any C or C++ library functions that might allocate or free memory while you are holding the corresponding operating system heap lock.

Even in a release build, you would still need to avoid any library functions that might allocate or release memory while holding a lock, which might be a problem if, for example, a hypothetical future implementation of `std::vector` was changed to make it thread-safe.

I recommend that you avoid the issue entirely, which is probably best done by creating a dedicated heap for your worker thread and taking all necessary memory allocations out of that heap.  It would probably be best to exclude this heap from processing; the documentation for `HeapWalk` does not *explicitly* say that you should not modify the heap during enumeration, but it seems risky.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing it. Let me ask though, as I'm still not following it. So like you said, the main thread called all those CRT functions that requested a lock on the heap. That's all good. Say, at the same time, my worker thread called `HeapLock` to do its `HeapWalk`-ing. But why would it deadlock? The first of those functions will return yielding execution to another. As for my use of `std::vector` inside the `HeapLock`-ed area, I changed the code to pre-allocate memory before it, so it shouldn't be calling any more heap allocations. It still didn't change the outcome though.

Comment: There are two separate locks involved.  I think the third and fourth paragraphs describe this as clearly as is possible: one thread has the CRT lock and is waiting for the OS lock, and your worker thread has the OS lock and is waiting for the CRT lock.  If you post the modified code, I'll look it over, but if you're getting the same symptoms the cause is probably the same - *something* that is allocating or freeing memory, or otherwise causing an attempt to claim the CRT lock.  If you check out the stack dump for the worker thread, it should be obvious.

Comment: Yeah, you might have a point. Let me try with just plain Win32 and a buffer on the stack for the `HeapLock/Unlock` part. It's a race condition though so I'm not sure how quickly I'll be able to reproduce it. I'll update it here ...

Comment: I think you got it, my friend. I ran the updated code overnight and throughout the day today and it worked fine. So instead of using `std::vector` I preallocated a buffer large enough using `new` before calling `HeapLock` and filled it in instead. I should admit that I did not know that CRT functions were using their own `lock` besides the critical section already implemented in `HeapAlloc`. Moreover they all (`CString` and `std::vector`) seem to be using the same `lock` somewhere internally, as otherwise I would not have this issue. So thanks again for dedicating your time to review this!